# Black stains developed on the bottom on stainless steel pot

Tags: food-safety, chemistry, pot, stainless-steel, burnt

Black stains developed on the bottom on stainless steel pot.
These are coming back after cleaning the pot when I cook chicken. **What are these, whether it is possible to get rid of these and it is it still safe to use this cooking pot?**

[image: Bottom of the cooking pot with stains]

---

Here are the details.

> When cooking soup, the water evaporated and the food badly burned in this pot.
> To clean it from this thick black layer of charcoal on the bottom of the pot, I had to boil this pot with salt, soap, and baking soda, apply Scotch-Brite, etc.
>
> I noticed that some small pits (scratches) developed after that cleaning on the bottom of this pot. These pits were not black, but after I boiled chicken in this pot, these pits became black.
>
> I cleaned the pot again - with soap (Ajax), vinegar, and tooth paste. When I boiled water in it, it was ok.
> However I boiled chicken in it, the black stains came back again.
>
> Again, cleaned it thoroughly using toothpaste (nothing else worked)
> The stains did not come back after boiling water, boiling water with salt or pepper, but came back after boiling chicken.
>
> What are these, is possible to get rid of these, and is it still safe to use this cooking pot (can I consume the food that was cooked in this pot)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleaning brown/gray spots on overheated stainless steel stock pot](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11916/cleaning-brown-gray-spots-on-overheated-stainless-steel-stock-pot)

Comment: @GdD I don't think this is a duplicate. The spots in the picture here aren't dirt spots as in the old question, they are pitting caused by the OP cleaning the pot aggressively

Comment: @GdD, no your suggested question does not answer this question (I saw it before my posting). My biggest concern here that the black stains are coming back

Comment: Are the spots *holes* through the stainless steel, and into some kind of base metal (aluminium, copper, ...) ?

Comment: @Kingsley, I don't think so. They are not that deep. When I look at these spot holes, I only see that very thin layer of the bottom (metal covering layer, pain layer thin) was scratched off

Comment: @user1234883 The holes don't need to be very deep to reach the base metal, only deeper than the thickness of the stainless cladding.

Comment: Thanks @Theodore. It it less than a mm? What would be the base metal if the holes got to it? Cu? Al? Ni?

Comment: @user1234883 The cladding thickness varies by product, but it is likely less than 1 mm.  The core may be Cu or Al for thermal mass, with a layer of carbon steel for strength.  See here: https://therationalkitchen.com/best-stainless-steel-cookware-sets/

Answer (score 1):

So long as the marks aren't holes through the stainless (see comments above - probably not).  I think [re-passivating the stainless steel](http://howtobrew.com/book/appendices/appendix-b/passivating-stainless-steel) may fix the issue.  Normally re-passivating stainless is done to treat rust.

Failing that, perhaps try a stronger acid like citric acid, or an acid-based cleaner.   You've already tried vinegar - which is a relatively *weak* acid.  (Note: vinegar should not damage 304/316 stainless steel, it's too weak). So I think trying something stronger may help.

Once the marks are gone, I would test-cook something of low-cost, and see if the spots return.  If they do, perhaps it really is micro-holes down through into the base-layers.

And it's not pertinent to the question, but seems relevant: soaking stainless steel in strong alkaline solutions - especially bleach, will pit the metal.  If you feel the need to wash stainless with bleach, be quick! No soaking.